# how to load a popup with data and return selected option to the original form

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a form where user can select an image out of list of images.
I would like to have a button "Select image".
When button is pressed there should be pop-up or overlay with the list of available images.
When user selects an image, the id of image should be returned to the original form.

I totally have no clue how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: there is no need for you to down-vote a valid question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty simple:

1. On click of "Select", show a div (mark it with high zindex to have popup behaviour or use jQuery dialog)
2. On this popup add all your images (whether you would like to add the images in html table or use div is upto you)
3. Add listener to your images (if all your images have a single class then somehting like :

jQuery('.imgclass').click)

1. When user close this div, use the id which you will capture in step 3.